VBA Excel : using quotes within a method that combines number and variable
I tried everything to select multiple cells which are not in a row or column but separate cells using the Range command.
The first line of code in the Sub is a recorded macro when selecting different separate cells.
That's what I want to do in a For-Loop sequence using variables.
To select cells using the loop and variables i have to concatenate the column letter and the variable. The column letter is in quotes. And the Range command is also in quotes. That where it is going wrong I believe.
Tried three thing to avoid the double quotes problem. But non of then work in my situation.
Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.
Sub test()

    ActiveSheet.Range("D5, D1, F6").Select

End Sub

Sub multiple()

    Dim weeknumber As Range

    For TaskRow = 1 To 1

        ' Set weeknumber = Union(Range("C" & TaskRow), Range("E" & TaskRow)).Select
        ' Set weeknumber = Range(CHR(34)"C" & TaskRow, "E" & TaskRow CHR(34)").Select

        weeknumber = Range("""C"" & TaskRow, ""E"" & TaskRow").Select

    Next TaskRow

End Sub


 Another example of the pitfalls of using Select which is almost never required and can result in many issues. See How to Avoid Using Select in Excel VBA

A fix of your code could look like that
Sub multiple()

    Dim weeknumber As Range
    Dim TaskRow As Long
    For TaskRow = 1 To 1
        ' Set weeknumber = Union(Range("C" & TaskRow), Range("E" & TaskRow)).Select
        ' Set weeknumber = Range(CHR(34)"C" & TaskRow, "E" & TaskRow CHR(34)").Select
        
        ' You have to use set when assigning an object variable
        ' you have to build a string like in your recorded code
        Set weeknumber = Range("C" & TaskRow & ", E" & TaskRow)

    Next TaskRow
    
    ' Select is usually not neccessary
    ' but for the sake of it
    weeknumber.Select


End Sub

The Select method is often unnecessary because you can directly manipulate objects such as ranges, cells, and worksheets without selecting them first. This approach makes the code more efficient and easier to read.
Avoiding Select can make your code run faster. When you select an object, VBA has to switch the focus to that object, which takes additional processing time.
How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA

The Range method requires a string as input. Since the expression is a string no further converts are needed.
You can't set the object variable with Select because the method's return value is a True or False result.
You can do it in this way:
set weeknumber = Range("C" & TaskRow & ":E" & TaskRow)
weeknumber.Select


Reference Non-Contiguous Cells in Single Row

When the non-contiguous cells are in a single row (column), you could reference the cells in the first row (column) of the first column (row) and use the Range.Offset property in the loop.

Main
Sub ReferenceNonContiguousRows()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    ' Store the number of tasks in a 'Long' variable
    ' (you would calculate this in a real-life scenario).
    Const TasksCount As Long = 3
    ' Store the columns (strings or numbers) in a 1D zero-based 'Variant' array.
    Dim Cols() As Variant: Cols = VBA.Array("H", "F", "E", "C")
    
    ' Reference the objects.
    
    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    ' Use the 'RefRowFromColumns' function
    ' to reference the non-contiguous cells in the first row.
    Dim frg As Range: Set frg = RefRowFromColumns(ws, Cols)
    
    ' Loop.
    
    Dim rrg As Range, cell As Range, r As Long, c As Long
    
    ' Loop through the rows,...
    For r = 1 To TasksCount
        ' ... use the 'Range.Offset property' to reference the cells
        ' in the same columns of the current row...
        Set rrg = frg.Offset(r - 1)
        ' ... and print the current row range's address
        ' to the Immediate window (Ctrl+g).
        Debug.Print "Row" & r & " : " & rrg.Address(0, 0)
        ' Note that when you loop through the cells of the row range,
        ' the cells are referenced in the order given in the array
        ' except when there are adjacent columns ('E:F') which are referenced
        ' from left to right as illustrated in this example
        ' (in the later case, best specify sorted from left to right).
        c = 0
        For Each cell In rrg.Cells
            c = c + 1
            Debug.Print "Cell" & c & ": " & cell.Address(0, 0)
        Next cell
    Next r
    
End Sub

Help
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      For a single row ('RowNumber') of a worksheet ('ws'),
'               creates a reference to the cells in columns
'               specified in an array ('RowColumns').
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefRowFromColumns( _
    ws As Worksheet, _
    RowColumns() As Variant, _
    Optional RowNumber As Long = 1) _
As Range
            
    Dim rg As Range, cell As Range, c As Long
    
    For c = LBound(RowColumns) To UBound(RowColumns)
        Set cell = ws.Cells(RowNumber, RowColumns(c))
        If rg Is Nothing Then Set rg = cell Else Set rg = Union(rg, cell)
    Next c
    
    Set RefRowFromColumns = rg
        
End Function

Results
Row1 : H1,E1:F1,C1
Cell1: H1
Cell2: E1
Cell3: F1
Cell4: C1
Row2 : H2,E2:F2,C2
Cell1: H2
Cell2: E2
Cell3: F2
Cell4: C2
Row3 : H3,E3:F3,C3
Cell1: H3
Cell2: E3
Cell3: F3
Cell4: C3

